Unexpected keyword argument 'constant_memory'
I need to improve the performance of the Excel writer part of my code and referred to xlsxwriter and pandas documentation.
import pandas as pd  
...    
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', engine_kwargs={"constant_memory": True})   


I see a TypeError: Workbook.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'constant_memory' runtime error after adding the engine_kwargs. Am I doing something wrong?

The Workbook parameter is options, so:
engine_kwargs={'options': {"constant_memory": True}}

